# asmx service hosting under sharepoint - recommendations

Tags: sharepoint, asmx

I have a SharePoint web application that has some custom web parts that consume an asmx web service. This service talks to an Oracle 10g database. Currently, the service is hosted on the application server in its separate web site (and port). I think I should host it on the front end servers under the _vti_bin folder to automatically achieve high availability and load balancing of the service calls. Would you recommend this "enhancement"?

Please notice that the asmx service is configured to run in a 32 bit app pool since oracle client, which it uses, is 32 bit software. I think then I can’t just have it under _vti_bin, I may need to have it in its own virtual directory under the SharePoint application’s IIS web site and configure that VD to run in a separate 32 bit app pool. Will that work out? Will I still achieve the HA and LB benefits knowing that Windows NLB is used?

Another related question; should the service be hosted on the WFE in the first place? It hits an external database which I could think of as a middle tier service that can be kept on the application server(s); one more server to be added soon 